# Difference between V @ HSV space and Y @ YUV space

Tags: image, image-processing

Seems like that both V @ HSV and Y @ YUV represents brightness? Which one is better for brightness representation? or any other better indicator for measurement of image brightness?

Answer (score 5):

The Y in YUV according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) is the sum of the three RGB components multiplied with some constants:

```
Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B
```

The V in HSV according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) is the value is defined as the largest component of a color:

```
V = M = max(R, G, B)
```

The answer is thus no, they are not the same.

### EDIT

The two color spaces have two different backgrounds, the HSV model *rearranges the geometry of RGB in an attempt to be more intuitive and perceptually relevant than the cartesian (cube) representation.* And the YUV model *encodes a color image or video taking human perception into account, allowing reduced bandwidth for chrominance components, thereby typically enabling transmission errors or compression artifacts to be more efficiently masked by the human perception than using a "direct" RGB-representation.*

So more suitable or better representation depends on your application.

Comment: I know the formula for these two are not equal. I mean which one is more suitable for representation of brightness.